# MirrorSourceConnector not consuming

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I have the following connector running in Kafka-Connect:

```
{
  "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector",
  "sync.topic.acls.enabled": "false",
  "topics": "foo",
  "topic.rename.format": "bar",
  "source.cluster.alias": "mycluster",
  "target.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "server01:9092",
  "sync.topic.configs.enabled": "false",
  "source.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "server01:9092"
}
```

When a Message (containing a string) is produced into *foo* nothing is ever mirrored to *bar*.
When looking at the saved consumer offsets for *foo* there are none.

So I would expect for something in `MirrorSourceConnector` to not work. Sadly I cannot seem to find any error message in the logs and Rest API is reporting connector to be `RUNNING`.

Is there a way to find out what is actually wrong and get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source, `MirrorSourceConnector` is not handling anything outside of Happy-Path. As such, it is not prepared to use the same cluster and goes off the rails (Topic bombs the Kafka Cluster).

Also, the Connect cluster bootstrap servers need to match the `target.cluster.bootstrap.servers`.